# How to programmatically dismiss NSAlert from runModal()?

Tags: cocoa

I have an `NSAlert` that I present in my Cocoa app via `runModal()`. I would like to unit test this behavior. Is there any way I can dismiss the alert programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

See `NSApplication`: `stopModal()`, `stopModal(withCode:)`, `abortModal()`, ...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19803170)

Comment: @Alejandro Q: how do you programmatically dismiss an `NSAlert`? A: `stopModal()`. How does that not answer the question?